# TouchableOpacity making the whole screen touchable in react native

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

The below code is making the whole screen clickable other than the touchable button, how do I stop it and make only the button clickable.
Thank You.

```
<View style={styles.slide3}>
          <Text >And simple</Text>
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress= {() => this.handleStart(this.props.history)}
         //       hitSlop={{top: 1, bottom: 1, left: 1, right: 1}}
            >
              <Text >Start</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
```

My `style` is defined as:

```
var style = {
  slide3: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#92BBD9',
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure there is not a `TouchableOpacity` component further up the hierarchy (ie an ancestor of the `<view>` your showing here)?

Comment: Avoid the white space after the opening text tag: `<Text >And simple</Text>` . Replace with this: `<Text>And simple</Text>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had same bug. I had to remove `paddingVertical` on the `<Text>` component.

Answer (score 1):

just replace `<View style={styles.slide3}>` with `<View style={style.slide3}>`

Comment: it's simply because in the code you use styles but you declare style variable. without s. actually, it's a typo error